# How to query a date that have 20 or more documents in mongoDB in the same day and hour

Tags: database, mongodb, date, aggregation, repeat

I have a mongoDB database structure like this

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: string,
  scheduledDate: ISOString
}
```

I want to return all scheduledDates that repeat the same scheduledDate day 2 times or more across all the database

Example:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'example1',
  scheduledDate: "2022-04-15T05:44:00.000Z"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'example1',
  scheduledDate: "2022-04-15T07:44:00.000Z"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'example1',
  scheduledDate: "2022-04-18T02:44:00.000Z"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'example1',
  scheduledDate: "2022-04-18T02:20:00.000Z"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'example1',
  scheduledDate: "2022-04-18T02:44:00.000Z"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'example1',
  scheduledDate: "2022-04-10T05:44:00.000Z"
}
```

In this example 2022-04-15 repeats 2 times and 2022-04-18 repeat 3 times, so both match the criteria (2 times or more) so I want to return both date day
Is this possible?

Like this:

```
{
  scheduledDate:"2022-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"
},
{
  scheduledDate:"2022-04-18T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

And one more question, is possible to do the same with hours? A list of specific hours of scheduledDate that repeat across all database X times

Answer (score 1):

Use `$group` with `$date` and `$dateTrunc`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: { $toDate: "$scheduledDate" },
          unit: "day"
        }
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: { $gt: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      scheduledDate: "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SEdoIIct5p5)

Comment: Using `{ $match: {} }` is pointless